# Can anyone explain this DOS hello world for emu8086?

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, emu8086

```
.Model Small
.STACK

.DATA
      MSG1 DB \"HELLO! How r u?$\"

.CODE

   MOV AX,@DATA
   MOV DS,AX

   lea dx,MSG1
   mov ah,09h
   int 21h

   mov ah,4ch
   int 21h

END
```

Answer (score 3):

### What it means.

> ```
> .Model Small
> ```

The program conforms to the *small* memory model where the code and data segments are different and don't overlap. The program can have no more than 65536 bytes of code and no more than 65536 bytes of data **and** stack. The program uses *near* pointers.

> ```
> .STACK
> ```

Nothing was mentioned here and so the stack assumes a default size. You can look it up in the emu8086 manual.

> ```
> .DATA
> MSG1 DB \"HELLO! How r u?$\"
> ```

This `.DATA` section contains a single string `HELLO! How r u?$`

> ```
> .CODE
> MOV AX,@DATA
> MOV DS,AX
> ```

These instructions make the `DS` segment register point to the `.DATA` section of your program thereby allowing access to that single string.

> ```
> lea dx,MSG1
> mov ah,09h
> int 21h
> ```

The offset address of that one string is loaded in the `DX` register. Then a DOS api call is made to display the characters of the string on the screen. The **$** character serves as an end-of-string indicator and is not shown on the screen.

> ```
> mov ah,4ch
> int 21h
> ```

This DOS api call terminates the program.

> ```
> END
> ```

Just a syntax requirement.